# XPATH expression to output parent node and matched child node excluding unmatched child node

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Below is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <object>book</object>
    <bookname>
        <value>testbook</value>
        <author>
            <value>ABCD</value>
            <category>
                <value>story</value>
                <price>
                    <dollars>200</dollars>
                </price>
            </category>
        </author>
        <author>
            <value>EFGH</value>
            <category>
                <value>fiction</value>
                <price>
                    <dollars>300</dollars>
                </price>
            </category>
        </author>
    </bookname>
</library>
```

I need the xpath expression to get the below output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <object>book</object>
    <bookname>
        <value>testbook</value>
        <author>
            <value>ABCD</value>
            <category>
                <value>story</value>
                <price>
                    <dollars>200</dollars>
                </price>
            </category>
        </author>
    </bookname>
</library>
```

But when i apply the below xpath expression, im getting the entire input xml as transformed output. Instead i need only the parent nodes + child node matching author/value='ABCD' (as shown above)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/library/object[text()='book']/../bookname/value[text()='testbook']/../author/value[text()='ABCD']/../../.."/>
```

Please help me with the correct xpath expression to get the desired output.

I'm using a java program to evaluate the xpath expression to get my desired XML output. And so I need an xpath expression. Below is my java code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("books.xml");

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/library/object[text()='book']/../bookname/value[text()='testbook']/../author/value[text()='ABCD']/../../..");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
```

Please help me with correct solution either in **Java or xslt**

Comment: I doubt you can do this with an `xsl:copy-of` and a single XPath. You'll have to use a more complicated stylesheet (but the XPath expressions will be much more pleasant). It this your entire XSLT?

Comment: @Tom Actually im using a java program to evaluate the xpath expression to get my desired XML output. And so I requested for an xpath exression. Below is my Java code

`   XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr 
     = xpath.compile("/library/object[text()='book']/../bookname/value[text()='testbook']/../author/value[text()='ABCD']/../../..");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; `

Please help me with the correct solution either with Java or xslt.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in pure xpath.

This stylesheet will do what you want in XSL 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <!-- Idendtity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author[not(value eq 'ABCD')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet will do what you want in XSL 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- Idendtity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author[not(value = 'ABCD')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: could you please provide the code in xslt1.0 for the above implementation ?